# Elegant way to add property to each element in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

How can I using lodash, with minimum code transform an array like this:

```
['Alfa','Betta','Gamma','Delta']
```

into:

```
[
 { squad: 'Alfa'},
 { squad: 'Betta'},
 { squad: 'Gamma'},
 { squad: 'Delta'},
]
```

Comment: How about without a library -> `['Alfa','Betta','Gamma','Delta'].map(function(el) {
    return {squad: el};
});` -> http://jsfiddle.net/TD4TM/

Comment: @adeneo you should add this as an answer.

Comment: @Pavlo - Well, I didn't post it as answer as it doesn't really answer the question, which was how to do this with lodash, but it just seemed so easy in plain javascript. You don't need a library for everything (actually, you don't really need a library for anything).

Comment: Nonsense about not needing libraries, not only in general, but in this particular case: what if he needs to support browsers that don't provide array.map?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Lo-Dash (or Underscore):

```
_.map(['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta'], function (squad) {
    return { squad: squad };
});
```

In ES5:

```
['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta'].map(function (squad) {
    return { squad: squad };
});
```

In ES2015:

```
['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta'].map(squad => ({ squad }));
```

Answer (score -7):

```
<script>
    var arrayOfSquads=['Alfa','Betta','Gamma','Delta'];
    var arrayOfThingsThatHaveSquads=new Array();
    for(i=0;i<arrayOfSquads.length;i++)
    {
        arrayOfThingsThatHaveSquads.push({"squad":arrayOfSquads[i]});
    }
    console.log("What's lodash?");
</script>
```

Comment: lodash is similar to underscore: think "low dash" (an underscore is a dash that is "low")

Comment: It's not very elegant ;)

Comment: I always try to make my code difficult to read so that no one steals it.

Comment: @NickManning - That's the way to go, name your variables after your friends, use yoda conditions everywhere, and make it generally impossible to read, that way you'll never get fired as you're the only one who can figure out what's going on with the code.